# Get authorized user now mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure:

[image]

I need get last authorized user with status 'Signed in' without last status 'Signed off'. How I can do it?

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_loginhistory WHERE status = 'Signed in' ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

But this get me last authorized user `admin`, why? If he is `Signed off`. I need get `Igor`, because he is `Signed in` last.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what should be the output manually?

Comment: Please add further explanation to your algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that: first select more recent row for each `username` and use `JOIN` or another `SELECT` to see if it's a "in" or "off"

**EDIT**: the concept is the same but corrected thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/7393478)

Version i don't fully understand: https://sqltest.net/#464377

```
SELECT *
FROM vtiger_loginhistory v_l
LEFT JOIN vtiger_loginhistory tmp
    ON (v_l.user_name = tmp.user_name AND v_l.login_time < tmp.login_time)
WHERE tmp.login_time IS NULL AND v_l.status = 'Signed in'
ORDER BY v_l.login_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Similar result with a subquery as I described (seems slower as explained in linked answer): https://sqltest.net/#464385

```
SELECT *
FROM vtiger_loginhistory v_l
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_name, MAX(tmp.login_time) AS maxlogintime
            FROM vtiger_loginhistory tmp GROUP BY user_name
            ORDER BY login_time DESC) tmp2
    ON (v_l.login_time = tmp2.maxlogintime)
WHERE status = 'Signed in' 
ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

**EDITED ORIGINAL NOT WORKING VERSION**: (because `GROUP BY` keeps the first row met, so the oldest dates)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM vtiger_loginhistory 
    GROUP BY user_name
    ORDER BY login_time DESC
) as temp
WHERE status = 'Signed in' 
ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get this result: Array ( [login_id] => 285 [user_name] => test [user_ip] => 192.168.88.67 [logout_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [login_time] => 2019-01-03 17:48:11 [status] => Signed in ) Why I get old singed user?

Comment: this is strange, I included this row into the test and still get "Igor": [see updated](https://sqltest.net/#464078). Is it the last updated version you tried?

Comment: Noo, see please screenshots, I use: user_name

Comment: that's what I say, I used wrong field name, i'm updating the answer and examples

Comment: answer and examples are updated (it's not supposed to be important if field `login_ip` is missing in the examples)

Comment: what do you get if you run only inner query like in [this example](https://sqltest.net/#464119)?

Comment: That's right, it's because `GROUP BY` keeps the first row met for each user_name, keeping the oldest one. I updated the tests to reflect that (oldest dates inserted first) and updated the answer

Comment: Worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check for username that is not IN the list for  signed  off too

```
SELECT * 
FROM vtiger_loginhistory 
WHERE status = 'Signed in' 
AND username NOT IN (
  select username 
  from vtiger_loginhistory 
  where  status = 'Signed OFF' 
)
ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is not working :(. Igor have a `Singed off` status down... I need get singed in only last and without status `singed off`

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way by using `not exists`

```
 select t1.* from vtiger_loginhistory t1
 where 
  status = 'Signed in'
 and not exists ( select 1 from vtiger_loginhistory t2 
                  where t2.user_name=t1.user_name 
                  and status = 'Signed off') 
 order by STR_TO_DATE(login_time,'%Y%m%d %h%i') DESC LIMIT 1
```

i think your login_time column is not datetime

Comment: No. I don't need pass `admin`)

Comment: I get this result: Array
(
    [login_id] => 285
    [user_name] => test
    [user_ip] => 192.168.88.67
    [logout_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [login_time] => 2019-01-03 17:48:11
    [status] => Signed in
) Why I get old singed user?

Comment: @Dronaxer does login column datetime or varchar?

Comment: login_time have a `datetime` column type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189113/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-dronaxer).

Answer (score 0):

There are many `Signed in` and `Signed off` user, the `admin` has signed off but the last signed in is more recent than `Igor`.

There are 2 solutions for you :

1. Renew the flow, when user `Signed off` just update the status instead of create new record
2. Create `top1signedoff` temporary table first and select the other not in `top1signedoff`

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE top1signedoff SELECT username FROM vtiger_loginhistory WHERE status = 'Signed off' ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1;

   SELECT * FROM vtiger_loginhistory
       WHERE status = 'Signed in' 
       and username Not IN (
           SELECT username FROM top1signedoff 
       )
   ORDER BY login_time DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Following query should give you the desired result

```
SELECT t.login_id,t.user_name, t.logout_time,t.login_time,t.status
FROM vtiger_loginhistory t
WHERE t.login_id = (
            SELECT MAX(t2.login_id)
            FROM vtiger_loginhistory t2
            WHERE t2.user_name = t.user_name
            GROUP BY t2.user_name
        )
    AND t.status = 'Signed in';
```

What we are doing here..

in sub-query we are fetching last `login_id` for user

and in main query we are checking if the `status` for that `login_id` is `'Signed in'`